# Capturar firma en tablet con Visual Studio 2019 y C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Quisiera que en una tablet `Surface`, el usuario pueda firmar con su dedo o lápiz y pueda guardar esa imagen en `SQL Server`, en un campo de tipo `Image`.

No consigo saber que tipo de componente, debo usar para capturar esa imagen y luego ya seguro que sabre pasarlo a `SQL Server Azure`.

Utilizo programación en `VS 2019` y `C#`.

¿Alguien ha programado esto en `Visual Studio` y `C#`?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Pues si estas desarrollando una aplicacion universal de windows te recomiendo que uses el control InkCanvas busca info a cerca de esto es sencillo de usar y solo debes implementar el guardado y carga de la firma.

Comment: Hola, estoy haciendo una aplicacion Windows Form, no se si ese control sirve para esto. Gracias

Comment: Lee esto por favor https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform. Este tipo de preguntas tan amplias y sin un trasfondo implícito de trabajo o investigación por parte del interlocutor, no son exactamente a las que yo respondería.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes dibujar en un `PictureBox` usando la funcionalidad de [gdi](/questions/tagged/gdi), el dibujo seria la firma

[C# tips : How to draw on a picturebox image using mouse by c#](https://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/c-tips-how-to-draw-on-a-picturebox-image-using-mouse-by-c/)

Usas los eventos `MouseDown` y `MouseMove` que son los mismos que deberia lanzar el touch sobre la pantalla

Del control PictureBox puedes obtener el `Image` resultante para persistir en la tabla

Comment: Gracias Leandro por la indicacion. Ese ejemplo tiene la problematica que necesita una imagen incorporada para escribir encima de ella. Lo he implementado pero no me funciona. Sin embargo, he encontrado este video que hace la captura utilizando un Panel y voy a seguir por aqui. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVPHEIJX-uw

Comment: La implementacion del video del ejemplo si que funciona y estoy ahora viendo como paso un MemoryStream hacia un Byte[] que es como se representa el campo de tipo Imagen del Sql Server. Espero dar con ello.

Answer (score 0):

Pues te sugiero que migres a aplicaciones Universal Windows Platform son aplicaciones principalmente para interactuar con acciones de touch screen (tabletas, mobiles,...)
pero si quieres seguir con el mismo tipo de aplicacion Picture Box es tu control, lee algo a cerca de GDI y acciones del mouse para capturar la firma.

Comment: Gracias, pero tiene que ser una aplicacion Windows Form. Buscare algo de lo que me comentas, mientras espero que aparezca alguien que tenga algun ejemplo claro y que lo haya usado. Saludos

Comment: Te sugiero que inicies la investigacion no te llevara mas de una tarde encotrar algo ademas de que debes ajustarlo a tus necesidades. Finalmente como tu pregunta es amplia lo mas probable es que sea cerrada. antes de que alguien te de una solucion